# getting pictures from twitter feed

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello i have a atom feed from twitter and every entry looks like this:

```
<entry>
    <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:9708181705990144</id>
    <published>2010-11-30T20:39:45Z</published>
    <link type="text/html" href="http://twitter.com/eva_starlily/statuses/9708181705990144" rel="alternate"/>
    <title>@sarahpalinusa If I'd used language like Willow did, for ANY reason whatsoever, my Dad would have grounded me for months. Learn to parent.</title>
    <content type="html">&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/sarahpalinusa&quot;&gt;@sarahpalinusa&lt;/a&gt; If I&amp;apos;d used language like Willow did, for ANY reason whatsoever, my Dad would have grounded me for months. Learn to parent.</content>
    <updated>2010-11-30T20:39:45Z</updated>
    <link type="image/png" href="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1179401088/b6c2b6ec-3432-476b-9ded-473986f12fd5_normal.png" rel="image"/>
    <twitter:geo>
    </twitter:geo>
    <twitter:metadata>
      <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
    </twitter:metadata>
    <twitter:place>
      <twitter:id>8c9bcefd88d617fe</twitter:id>
      <twitter:full_name>Greenwood - Coxwell, Toronto</twitter:full_name>
      <twitter:type>neighborhood</twitter:type>
    </twitter:place>
    <twitter:source>&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;</twitter:source>
    <twitter:lang>en</twitter:lang>
    <author>
      <name>eva_starlily (Laura)</name>
      <uri>http://twitter.com/eva_starlily</uri>
    </author>
  </entry>
```

now i would like to have the url from the second link tag wich is the poster image.
How can i select this within as3? I tried the following:

```
for each(var entryXML:XML in resultXML.rootNamespace::entry)
            {
                    trace(entryXML.rootNamespace::link.@href);


            }
```

But this also gives me the href from the first link. So how can i filter this so i only get the href from the second link?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var imageUrl : String = entryXml.link.(@type=="image/png").@href;
```